# Is it possible to emulate printing to a specific printer?

Tags: windows, pdf, printer, printing

I'm developing a Windows application that should support printing to a group of specific printers (for instance, Bixolon SRP-350, etc.) Those are special printers with special paper dimensions, etc. I need to test my software with them. Obviously one solution would be to buy each of those printers, so before I jump into doing that, I'm curious, is there such thing as `printer emulation` or a `virtual printer` available?

Here's what I need. You know when you install a PDF printer, it prints into a pdf file instead of the paper, right. So if there's a software that would allow me to see how my print would look for a specific printer by outputting the result to PDF or anything on the screen with a ruler on the side for dimensions, that's what I'm looking for. At this point I'm just checking if such solution even exists?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install the needed printer without having it connected, then use the "Print to file" option in the standard "Print" dialog box.

*(Someone who actually has tried this please expand... I just know it's possible.)*

Comment: That is a very clever solution. I can't image I didn't think of it myself :) Let me see if I can download a test driver without having an actual printer....

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately when I installed a driver for `Bixolon SRP-350` it installed OK but I couldn't see it in the list of printers to try it.

Comment: @ahmd1: Then install an actual printer; I'm sure the Printers control panel has an "Add Printer" option which lets you select any model.